# making an image responsive according to screen in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a bootstrap carousel which takes full width and height of the screen.
However when the screen-size is less than 600px,it looks like[image]

clearly there is a **gap at bottom**,which i **do not** want.
at small size(<600px) i want the image to be like :
[image]

So that there is no bottom margin and only left part of the image is displayed.
Can it be achieved with css .My code is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNqMaa). Thanks in Advance.
Relevant css and html are as follows:

```
<header>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/65/29/U5VN6e.jpg" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="100%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/65/29/U5VN6e.jpg" alt="Chania" width="100%" height="100%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/65/29/U5VN6e.jpg" alt="Flower" width="100%" height="100%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/65/29/U5VN6e.jpg" alt="Flower" width="100%" height="100%">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html
    {height:100%;
        margin:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    body
    {   margin:0;
        height:100%;
    }

    header{

        height:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with background images instead of image tags (there is a problem with img tag and aspect ratio):

CSS:

```
.image {
  background-image: url(http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/65/29/U5VN6e.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.item > .image').css('height', $(window).height());
}).trigger('resize');
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/QdVEra)